# UWSGI Why would there be unattended requests . According to the log

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, wsgi

I've got the below in my uwsgi log running with Django and Nginx. The req: -/- field i believe is referring to the request count and the total number of requests respectively. They're both incrementing gradually but the gap is not being closed. I'm not sure what this means for my application as it looks like there're unattended requests that will never be attended. I've checked around but still didn't get the right answer to the situation.

`[pid: 305785|app: 0|req: 418/1873] 99.7.107.127 () {38 vars in 554 bytes} [Tue Nov 14 23:30:43 2023] GET /api/machines/endpoint/ => generated 385 bytes in 10 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 7 headers in 215 bytes (1 switches on core 0)`

`[pid: 305785|app: 0|req: 419/1874] 99.7.107.127 () {38 vars in 562 bytes} [Tue Nov 14 23:30:43 2023] GET /api/machines/endpoint/ => generated 545 bytes in 40 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 7 headers in 215 bytes (1 switches on core 0)`

I'm expecting there'd be so little gap between the request count and the total number requests. I should also mention that this persists even after restarting the service itself. Perhaps some explanation on this behavior would clear my confusions .

Answer (score 0):

After some back and forth. I found the below statement and it all makes sense

*req: N/M -> N is the number of managed requests by the current worker for
the specific app, M is the grand total (sum of all requests of all
workers)*

This means what I'm seeing in the log is the count for the current worker and there're about 4 worker processes. summing all their count would amount to the total. So there're actually no unattended requests. it's just me not understanding the log well enough.